# BasicTabbedPaneUI.tabPane becomes null - what could cause that and how can I debug it?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

For better readability, I've moved some of the code that generates my GUI in classes. Unfortunately I had to make a mistake somewhere because now I'm getting this error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" `java.lang.NullPointerException`
>     at
>   `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$ScrollableTabSupport.updateView(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java`:`3351`)

It happens in `javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicTabbedPaneUI.java` on this line:

```
       private void updateView() {
ERROR HERE: int tabPlacement = tabPane.getTabPlacement();
            int tabCount = tabPane.getTabCount();
```

There's a method in this class that can set the `tabPane` to null, but I'm definitelly not calling it:

```
public void uninstallUI(JComponent c) {
    uninstallKeyboardActions();
    uninstallListeners();
    uninstallDefaults();
    uninstallComponents();
    c.setLayout(null);

    this.tabPane = null;
}
```

I create the tabbed GUI using my TabbedWindow class:

```
public final JTabbedPane container;
  public TabbedWindow() {
    container = new JTabbedPane();
    container.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
    //More code but nothing with container
  }
```

I then append it to the main JPane:

```
public void createTabs(Container pane) {
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    System.out.println("Creating tabbed window.");
    TabbedWindow win = new TabbedWindow();
    //Inbetween, I append some JFrames to the win.container
    //Adding to main pane:
    pane.add(win.container);
    System.out.println("Done.");
```

My questions now are:

1. What could be causing this problem in the java library? Why doesn't it throw more helpful exception?
2. How can I debug this problem and find out what's wrong?

Comment: Does your `installUI()` call `super.installUI()` so that `tabPane` gets set in the first place?

Comment: I do not extend from that class. The `installUI()` is being called (as I checked using debugger), but not from any method familiar to me. Basically the whole thing happens without any of my code appearing in the call stack.

Comment: **1.** I don't use the `BasicTabbedPaneUI` directly. I use `JTabbedPane` class according to some Java tutorial. It worked before I rewrote the code. **2.** I don't understand, what do you mean?

Comment: It's difficult to tell anything without knowing more of the code, or even seeing the full stack trace. Shooting in the dark anyway: do you possibly violate the [swing threading rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)? That could result in inconsistent state of the components where the component has non null UI, but the UI does not yet have a reference to the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be sure about the real reasons, but the `uninstallUI` has been invoked because I used `container.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);` **before appending other elements**.

Because I frankly doesn't understand how the whole thing works I decided to go the safe way:

```
  public void close() {
    container.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
    closed = true;
  }
```

And after calling close, nothing can be added to the GUI any more.

Comment: That also results in `installUI()` being called (in BasicTabbedPaneUI, at least), which should restore `tabPane`, so there must a be a bug somewhere that prevents that from being done, or results in `updateView()` being called before the `installUI()` call.

Comment: Maybe it happens as 2 threads are somehow running (but I don't start any threads at that point, so *not mine threads*).

Comment: Do you initialize the application [correctly](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)? It's easy to violate the threading rules accidentally, and unfortunately the net is full of sample code that is *incorrect*. That is, the thread entering `main()` is *not* the thread where swing does its work.

Comment: `I frankly doesn't understand how the whole thing works I decided to go the safe way:` - that is not the safe way. The `TabbedPaneDemo` found in the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Tabbed Pane` works for me whether the tabs are added to the tabbed pane or not. We have no idea of how the `close()` method is used in your code. Post a proper `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem then we will probably be able to give you a proper solution.

Comment: @kiheru At the start, I create no additional threads. Yes, I start the application correctly. Also note that before I've rewritten the code that generates `tabbedPane` contents, it worked. I've exactly described what caused the error and I'm sure it can be reproduced.

Comment: @camickr What is unsafe about my solution? My `close` method makes sure no contents are added once I call `.setTabLayoutPolicy`.

Comment: `I've exactly described what caused the error and I'm sure it can be reproduced.` - so post the SSCCE that demonstrates the problem. We can't guess what you have changed from the working version. Your verbal description and few random lines of code to not give us the context of how every works together. `What is unsafe about my solution?` - because you don't know why it appears to work and you will likely make the same mistake again in some other code.